# Download the last line from a webpage without downloading to a file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to download the last line of a webpage directly to a string variable with out an intermediate file using Powershell?

https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=20MICRONS&x=NSE&i=1800&p=1d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v

If the last line is empty or whitespaces, I need to pick the last line with characters.

I'm trying to pick the latest 30 min data of a stock from Google.

Answer (score 2):

The last line is an empty line, so maybe you were trying to select it, but you thought that you were doing something wrong.
If you count rows, there are 18 of them. 
For this particular case, just select row 16

```
$a = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=20MICRONS&x=NSE&i=1800&p=1d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v'

$a.Content.Split('')[16]
```

or you could select the last two lines from that result

```
$a.Content.Split('') | Select -Last 2
```

You can filter blank rows using [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6)

```
$a.Content.Split('') | Where-Object{$_} | Select-Object -Last 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have modified the question. Is there a way to get data without manually giving the line number

Comment: Getting the error: Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline. $a.Content.Split('') | [Where-Object][1]{$_} | Select-Object -Last 1

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake when editing @Vladiimir's answer, remove the square brackets